# Use the first column to add a row between groups of items in table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this, the first column identifies the group the row belongs to and the second column is the actual data.

```
+--------+--------+
|Column A|Column B|
+--------+--------+
|A       |1       |
|A       |2       |
|A       |3       |
|B       |2       |
|B       |3       |
|B       |4       |
+--------+--------+
```

I want to transform the table to look like this though, where there is a header row per se for each group.

```
+--------+--------+
|Column A|Column B|
+--------+--------+
|A       |NULL    |
|NULL    |1       |
|NULL    |2       |
|NULL    |3       |
|B       |NULL    |
|NULL    |2       |
|NULL    |3       |
|NULL    |4       |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: For what it's worth, that is not how relational database management systems work. Relational database management systems like MySQL deal in rectangular arrays of data. Each table, and each result set, contains a fixed number of columns of data, and is populated with zero or more rows. Rows in tables have no inherent order. Each row has the same format and number of columns as the other rows. If you want some kind of hierarchical setup with an array of detail rows under each master row, you need to generate that in an application program.

Comment: No, I'm fully aware. I'm trying to format this data for an email report in a hack-ish way.

Comment: mysql <> sql-server

Comment: The sql-server tag refers to Microsoft SQL server, please remove either mysql tag or sql-server tag to clarify what RDBMS is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN p.columnB is null THEN p.columnA END as ColumnA,
       p.columnB
FROM(
    SELECT distinct t.columnA as columnA,NULL as columnB
    FROM YourTable t
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT s.columnA,s.columnB
    FROM YourTable s) p
ORDER BY p.columnA,
         CASE WHEN p.columnB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 end
```

Though, if you plan on doing something with this data other then presenting it, I **strongly** suggest agasint it.